# Is it possible to export the whole Node.JS module without wrapping into a function/class?

Tags: node.js, module.exports

Is it possible to export the whole `Node.JS` module and have the following features:

1. Import this module from another module
2. Get all `methods` and `attributes` set into this module
3. I **do not want** to wrap any part of this code from my module into a function/class?

For example, I want to create a `REST.js` module which has the following attributes and methods:

```
let a = 10
let b = 20
const funcA = (x) => {
//functionA code
}
const funcB = (x, y) => {
//functionB code
}
```

This module needs to be imported into `app.js` using some syntax which enables me to use the following API (or similar) to get attributes and use methods from `REST.js`:

```
const REST = require('REST')

//get attributes
console.log(REST.a)
console.log(REST.b)

//use methods

let resA = REST.funcA(10)
let resB = REST.funcB(10, 20)
```

All in all, I want to know if there is a similar to `Python` syntax for using modules.

Comment: Just do `module.exports.funcA = (x) => ...`, `module.exports.funcB = (x,y) => ...`

Comment: @slebetman, unfortunately, it's not convenient. I need to export the whole module with all attributes and methods using one short command. In Python I do not even need to use module.exports, it does it automatically.

Comment: Node.js is not Python. Similarly Python cannot export functions like go where only uppercase functions are exported by the module but lowercase functions are automatically hidden because Python is not go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but in `NodeJS`, you must explicitly export the `variables/functions` like this:

```
let a = 10
let b = 20
const funcA = (x) => {
//functionA code
}
const funcB = (x, y) => {
//functionB code
}

module.exports = {
  a,
  b,
  funcA,
  funcB
}
```

Comment: Really must? Is there any trick like module.export = *?

Comment: No, as far as I know